# problem to rename youtube videos by pytube

Tags: python, youtube, playlist, pytube

i try to download a playlist and get a name for every video but i get many errors
the function to download playlist as audio annd get a name for every video
i'm using pytube

```
def AudioPlaylist(url):
    i = 1
    try:
        playlist = Playlist(url)
        print(playlist.title)
    except:
        print("Connection Error")
        exit()
    folder_name = filedialog.askdirectory()
    for video  in playlist.videos:
        name = str(video.title)
        audio = video.streams.get_audio_only()
        audio.download(output_path=folder_name,filename =f"{i}-{name}.mp3")
        i+=1
```

i got this error

```
File "d:\projects\Youtube\youtube.py", line 86, in AudioPlaylist
    audio.download(output_path=folder_name,filename =f"{i}-{name}.mp3")
  File "C:\Users\VIRUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pytube\streams.py", line 250, in download
    with open(file_path, "wb") as fh:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:/projects/Youtube/New folder\\1-Humood - Ha Anatha | حمود الخضر - فيديوكليب هأنذا | Music Video.mp3
```

can anyone helping me for solving this problem

Edite :
The problem with videos have an arabic name

'

Comment: Not sure but maybe Windows doesn't support arabic characters in file names.

Comment: Did you try creating a file with that name in Explorer? What happens if you do? What happens if you try doing it in the terminal?

Comment: thank for oyur helping i solve it i replace name = str(video.title) to video.title = f"{i}- video.title"