# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "Path\\to\\the\video\\file" - Pytube

Tags: python, pytube

I am trying to download a playlist from YouTube using Pytube.
I want to rename the videos as they are being downloaded sequentially:

```py
from pytube import Playlist

math_playlist = Playlist("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oI_C-l-dcPw&list=PLf0dYueVuajYt1LUolD6SizWt1ED6GU4B")


i = 1

folder = "T:\\Videos\\Mathematics\\"

for video in math_playlist.videos:
    title = video.title
    f_name = f"{i} - {title}"
    video.streams.get_highest_resolution().download(output_path=folder, filename=f_name)
```

I am getting the following error when I run the above code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:\YouTube_Video_Downloader\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    video.streams.get_highest_resolution().download(output_path=folder, filename=f_name)
  File "P:\YouTube_Video_Downloader\venv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\streams.py", line 312, in download
    with open(file_path, "wb") as fh:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "T:\\Videos\\Mathematics\\Video_Name"

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have looked up for the problem on Stackoverflow and got this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73885956/problem-to-rename-youtube-videos-by-pytube).
But it didn't help me much.

Answer (score 1):

Answer by @LITDataScience worked but I don't know why he/she deleted the answer.

Solution:
This code worked:

```
from pytube import Playlist

math_playlist = Playlist("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oI_C-l-dcPw&list=PLf0dYueVuajYt1LUolD6SizWt1ED6GU4B")


i = 1

folder = "T:\\Videos\\Mathematics\\"

for video in math_playlist.videos:
    title = re.sub(r'[^\w\-_\. ]', '_', video.title)
    f_name = f"{i} - {title}"
    video.streams.get_highest_resolution().download(output_path=folder, filename=f_name)
    i += 1
```

The Windows system doesn't allow a few characters in the file name. So the above regex replaces those characters with underscores.